# how to Copy group membership from one user to another in AD, when you have domain and 3 subdomains

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Copy group membership from one user to another in AD, when you have domain and 3 subdomains

```
$From = Read-Host -Prompt "From User"
$to = Read-Host -Prompt "To User"
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser -Server "Domainname" -Identity $From -Properties MemberOf
$Group = $CopyFromUser.MemberOf
$confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to Copy Group Membership from $From to $to ? Press 'y' to Proceed or any key to Cancel"
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
    $Group | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $to
    clear
    echo "($From) User's Group Memership  has been Copied to User  ($to)"
Pause
}
else {
Write-Host 'Task Cancelled'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using this as your starting point. You mentioned "Domainname" for server.

```
$Domain           = "domainname.local"
$From             = "yourusername"
$ServerHostname   = $(Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $Domain -Discover -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).HostName[0]
$CopyFromUser     = Get-ADUser -Server $ServerHostname -Identity $From -Properties MemberOf
$CopyFromUser.MemberOf
```

Then you can get a domain controller for each domain. That should work. :-)

With kind regards,
TheStingPilot